# TypeError: p is not a function highCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have problem with highcharts since 1 month. My code does not work form 1 month. This show me :

> Uncaught TypeError: p is not a function 
>   (anonymous function) @highcharts-more.js:21
>   (anonymous function) @highcharts-more.js:26
>   (anonymous function) @highcharts-more.js:8 
>   (anonymous function) @highcharts-more.js:8

I use hightCharts, I don't understand why this does not work since 1 month

```
$('#' + idEspaceModule).highcharts({
        series : donnees,
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        pane: {
            size: '70%'
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        xAxis: {
                  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                  categories: categories
              },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,
            showLastLabel: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Nombre'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value;
                }
            },
            reversedStacks: false
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                shadow: false,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPlacement: 'on'
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank's

Comment: add your full code.

Comment: Can you create the issue, e.g. on jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/77zf05uo/

Comment: @morganfree are you working at highcharts?